# Does URLConnection.getHeaderField() download the full file

Tags: java, date, http, header

I need to download the headers of some files in order to check the last modification date; the information is within the header 'last_modified'.

I need it in order to manage a local cache of distant file; on a regular basis I check whether the file has changed.

To achieve it:

```
URL u = new URL(url);
URLConnection connection = u.openConnection();
String lastModifiedHeader = connection.getHeaderField("Last-Modified");
connection.getInputStream().close();
```

It works great. Thus my question is: doing so, is the entire file downloaded, or just the headers (this is what I expect)?

Comment: You should set the request method to HEAD to ensure it isn't.